# Add Text to jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'd like to customise my Slider. It currently works like this: http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/examples/gotopage.html.

However, I was wondering, is it possible to associate a piece of text with each "slide".

So when you click the circle button to navigate, a new piece of text fades in (bottom left) and the old text fades out. Is this possible?

Many thanks for any pointers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution which works better: Malsup.

> http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/caption.php